# Mongoose findAndCount with where operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I had to rewrite some functionality which is using mongodb with mongoose. I have a function which doest findAndCount() from mongodb, but I'm not able to find id for mongoose. Right now I'm using this piece of code:

```
const [totalItems, items] = await Promise.all([
        model.estimatedDocumentCount(),
        model
            .find({
                ...where,
                ...(dateQuery && { createdAt: { ...dateQuery } }),
            })
            .skip(_limit * (_page - 1))
            .limit(_limit)
            .sort(sort)
            .populate(populate)
            .select(select),
    ]);
```

But I found out that the estimatedDocumentCount() is for the whole collection, lets say for example collection has 4 saved documents, but then comes some type of **where** filter and returned result from .find() is a **single element**, estimatedDocumentCount still returns 4 and i'm not able to calculate right pagination. To use .length it's not a option cuz there is **skip** and **limit**

My question is can I somehow get the count for all documents which are matching the filter? Thanks in advance!